# Fastest way to learn new difficult words to widen vocabulary?

Tags: vocabulary

I am training for the GRE. I am wondering what the fastest way to learn difficult words is. Recently, I have been using a method that puts a lot of words under an umbrella. For example:
**Umbrella term: education**
*cyclopedia*: a work containing information in all departments of knowledge
*erudition*: quality of having great knowledge
*opsimath*: education late in life
*polymathy*: having knowledge of many arts and sciences
*didactic*: moral instruction
**All of these words are learned in bulk, because they all relate to education. Is there a resource online that reflects this method, or is there a resource that does it better? Note that all these words are in current usage, they're not narrow & technical, yet they're very uncommon & rare. On a *frequency list* of vocabulary, they would show up at the bottom.**

Comment: You can’t really get much out of learning new pieces of active working vocabulary by lists. You have to actually see the word used in a larger narrative.  Read books.

Comment: I challenge the statement that the words "are in current use" not due to "a narrow technical definition", as the OP implies.  Is "ursuline" not "narrow and technical"? Would -- does -- anyone use "opsimath" except to *appear* erudite or in some very specific, narrow, technical sense?  The best way to start is to better identify which words you want to learn; else you're going to end up trying to memorize a dictionary (and a very historical and comprehensive one, at that).

Comment: @tchrist You may remember the old Readers Digest. Apart from its reactionary views the other thing I remember about it was a little section titled 'It pays to Increase your Word Power'. Every month it listed a few hard words and their meanings. But I can't now recall a single word I learned that way.  Wide reading, debate and written correspondence, are the only routes to good literacy.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I remember the old Readers Digest, and I too fail to remember ever learning a single word there. In contrast, I did sometimes learn new words from National Geographic articles. Sure, they weren’t always words that one could casually sneak into casual conversation or letters, but learn them I did, at least when the topic interested me. I still advise literature as a starting-point for vocabulary building, but if you must go for some periodical, these days I would probably advise *The Economist*. You’re right that you still have to use it to retain in.

Comment: "opsimath" is not registered in Longman DCE as a word of modern English vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to learn vocabulary is to use my "Head-to-Toe Method of Associations for Vocabulary Acquisition," but the method is a bit too complex to answer here. You can read a couple articles on the method at Academia.edu (http://wmich.academia.edu/PatrickTRandolph) or go to the MITESOL Selected Proceedings for 2013 (This can be found by going to the Eastern Michigan Digital Commons). Or you can go to the ITBE Link and read portions of it there. I've gotten students to learn a great deal by using this method, use the terms correctly, and feel comfortable in using them in various "registers." Also check the principles of this method called R.E.S.T.

Essentially, the best way to learn vocabulary is:

1. find connections with the terms and your life; e.g., if a person's face helps to learn or remember a word, then think of their face;
2. use them as much as possible; Hermann Ebbinghaus (1885/1913) did research that found
   we forget up to 90% of what we learn within 30 days. Much of this research has been reconfirmed rather robustly by recent research in neuroscience (Medina, 2009, Sousa, 2011). BUT, if you review the terms by using them on an hourly basis, you can turn that "90% of forgetting" into "90% of remembering."
3. add emotion to your learning; i.e., connect emotions with the words; again, think of or feel things, places, and people that will help you learn/remember the words.
   (Also see Willis, 2006.)
4. teach the words to friends, that is also a great way to keep them in your long-term memory.

But if you are highly motivated, that, in itself, will help you over the long haul.

As one pointed out, vocabulary isn't learned by using lists. It is learned by feeling
the language and making as many neural connections (Willis, 2006; Jensen, 2011) as possible to keep the terms in your working and ultimately in your long-term memory.

Good luck!